# HTACCESS Redirection to HTTPS by keeping any domain in between?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

How to redirect something like:

```
http://www.example.com/site1/admin
http://www.example.com/site2/hello/admin
http://www.example.com/site3/world/admin
http://www.example.com/.......etc....../admin
```

.. will be redirected to:

```
https://www.example.com/site1/admin
https://www.example.com/site2/hello/admin
https://www.example.com/site3/world/admin
https://www.example.com/.......etc....../admin
```

Which mean the sites:

- Starting with `http`
- And, ending with `/admin`

.. will be redirected to themselves with `https`.

I'm not good in apache mod_rewrite rules. Please help to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*/admin) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```